# Auto-tweet PHP suddenly stopped working. thmOauth reveals "unknown message digest algorithm."

Tags: php, curl, twitter, oauth

My PHP auto-tweet script stopped working on July 28. Tracing the problem, it looks like I'm not even connecting to Twitter; the script fails to even connect.

I'm using the [tmhOAuth library](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth), and I can see an error (#35) in the tmhOAuth->response:

> error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message
>   digest algorithm

The research I've done indicates that could be some sort of an SSH problem, but I'm afraid it's all over my head. Do I need to change something on my hosted server? Is there some way to get more info? Is there any reason it would suddenly stop working on July 28?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Twitter have upgraded their SSL certificate to use the newer, more-secure SHA256 algorithm, rather than SHA1.

More people will be doing this in the future.

This was a bug in cURL (http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/848/) which was fixed in 2009. I suspect you need to upgrade libcurl to one of version 7.19.6 or above. Have a look at http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/ for information about PHP, and http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/ for help choosing which package to download.

Answer (score 0):

by upgrading opessl you can get over it.

```
  yum update openssl
```

will do it.